# C++ recursion repeating output

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    string command_one;
    int slot;
    cout<<"One chip or Quit?\n";
    getline(cin, command_one);
    if(command_one=="One chip"){
        cout<<"Pick a slot between 0 and 8 (inclusive)\n";
        cin>>slot;
        if(slot>=0 and slot<=8){
            double position=slot;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"This Option is invalid!\n";
            main();
        }
    }
    else if(command_one=="Quit"){
        cout<<"Have a nice day! :D";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"This Option is invalid!\n";
        main();
    }
}
```

When it hits the else loop nested in the if(command_one=="One chip") it returns 
"This Option is invalid!
One chip, Multi chip, or Quit?
This Option is invalid!
One chip, Multi chip, or Quit?"
But it should be:
"This Option is invalid!
One chip, Multi chip, or Quit?"
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Don't recurse into `main`? Generally you would make a new function for this and call it from `main`.

Comment: extract the recursive functionality to other method, don't use `main` to recurse. By the way this line: `double position=slot;` don't do anything.

Comment: clean up the trailing newline from your input stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin` doesn't take the `\n` character.`getline()` takes it as an empty line input. Put a `getchar()` to take that `\n` character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string command_one;
    int slot;
    cout<<"One chip or Quit?\n";
    getline(cin, command_one);
    if(command_one=="One chip")
    {
        cout<<"Pick a slot between 0 and 8 (inclusive)\n";
        cin>>slot;

        //putting a getchar() after cin

        getchar();
        if(slot>=0 and slot<=8)
        {
            double position=slot;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"This Option is invalid!\n";
            main();
        }
    }
    else if(command_one=="Quit")
    {
        cout<<"Have a nice day! :D";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"This Option is invalid!\n";
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you input number from keyboard and press enter the new line character '\n' is also taken that's why your program was generating output twice but placing a getchar() function after cin the getchar() function takes the new line character '\n' and the program generates output only once...

Answer (score 1):

```
cin>>slot;
```

This leaves the new-line character following the number in the stream's buffer. The next call to `getline` will find that, giving an empty line.

You can use [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to ignore the new-line character and any other garbage at the end of the line:

```
cin.ignore(-1, '\n'); // ignore any number of characters up to and including new-line
```

Note that calling `main` is not allowed (although some compilers might allow it); and unbounded recursion like this could eventually cause a stack overflow. Consider using a loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

[std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> Extracts characters from input and appends them to `str` until one of the following occurs (checked in the order listed)
>   a) end-of-file condition on input, in which case, `getline` sets `eofbit`.
>   b) the next available input character is `delim`, as tested by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`, in which case **the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to `str`.**

Therefore, you need to consume the leftover `\n` character.